# Overheating issue

Tags: overheating

I have a 1977 Ford F-250 with a 400 motor automatic. I have an overheating issue. Replaced the radiator and thermostat but it is still overheating. The fan and water pump seems to be working. Do I have a clutch fan in the water pump? Really at a loss and at my wits end.

Comment: Plugged radiator?

Comment: Fan clutch is mounted on the fan itself, not part of the pump internally.

Comment: No clutch fan and just put a brand new radiator, thermostat and thermostat housing and it is no longer leaking. Did notice leak on valve cover gasket now. Would that cause overheating issues as well?